# Move Files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, move, period

Using the code below as a base (from another question) how can I move files between 2 dates eg : >2wks AND < 13 Months to another location. Also is it possible to restrict the file extension to be moved?

```
get-childitem -Path "E:\source" |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | 
    move-item -destination "F:\target"
```

Comment: `Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-14) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-13) } `

Comment: `-and` your conditions. 2weeks => `(Get-Date).AddDays(-14)`, 13 Month `(Get-Date).AddMonths(-13)` In a move you change the location not the filename/extension, see `Get-Help Move-Item`

Answer (score 2):

Restricting the files to fetch with `Get-ChildItem` can be done in several ways.
The first is to use the `-Filter` parameter:

```
# set up the start and end dates
$date1 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$date2 = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-13)

# using -Filter if you want to restrict to one particular extension.
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\source" -Filter '*.ext' |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date1 -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date2} | 
    Move-Item -Destination "F:\target"
```

If you need to restrict to more than one extensions, you cannot do that with the `-Filter` parameter. Instead, you need to use the `-Include` parameter that can take an array of wilcard patterns.
Note that in order for the `-Include` to work, you must either also use the `-Recurse` switch, or have the path for `Get-ChildItem` end in `\*` like this:

```
# using -Include if you want to restrict to more than one extensions.
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\source\*" -Include '*.ext1', '*.ext2', '*.ext3' |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date1 -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date2} | 
    Move-Item -Destination "F:\target"
```

Then there's the `-Exclude` parameter that like the `-Include` also accepts a string array of wildcard parameters that will filter out the extensions you do NOT want.

If you need to filter on file attributes, like ReadOnly, Hidden etc., you could use the `-Attributes` parameter.

For these, have a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters)